# Enforce no merging while staged changes exist in git

Tags: git

I want to enforce (i.e. throw an error and fail) whenever I do a git merge with staged changes. Much in the same why a git rebase will not work if unstaged changes exist. Is there a way to do this?

The goal of this is to enforce a workflow like:

```
git stash
git pull #or git merge
git pop
```

Comment: Is this not already the case? `git help merge` states: "To avoid recording unrelated changes in the merge commit, git pull and git merge will also abort if there are any changes registered in the index relative to the HEAD commit." (Although note that this doesn't apply to _unstaged_ changes.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `git config branch.autosetuprebase true` and `git config branch.<name>.rebase true` (where `<name>` is any existing branch name). This would default `pull` to use `--rebase`.

Note: just like any merge/rebase, this may have conflicts.  The [git config manual page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) actively warns against this option.